# Debug Area Target Output messages

Tags: ios, swift2

My app is running without any error or warning but I have many messages like this in the Debug Area:

> [941] :CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to
>   see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental
>   variable.

and

> [941:296894]  - changing property
>   contentsGravity in transform-only layer, will have no effect

What do these warnings means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't mean anything. There are some bugs in iOS 9 that cause these messages. Ignore them.